# Border is outside the button in IE but not in FF, Chrome, Safari

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have created menu with tabs and under tabs I use `<button>`s. Normally `<button>` has `border:none;` attribute. When a user hovers `<button>` the class below is added to it.

```
    .hover {
           border-style:solid
           border-width:2px;
           border-color:rgb(160,36,67);
           };
```

Unhovered (on the right) `<button>` and hovered `<button>` can be seen here. 
[image]
(Sorry for the poor quality)

I get the first result firefox, safari and chrome. However in IE border appears outside the button and pushes the other elements in the page. I tried to use `max-height` `max-width` however result is the same.

I searched but could not find similar topic. Thanks for any help.

Edit: Added HTML

```
    <table id="ust3tab" class="tab" border="0" cellpadding="0"      cellspacing="0">  
      <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td class="td1"><button id="alt1" class="altbutton">TAB1</button></td>
        <td class="td1"><button id="alt2" class="altbutton">TAB2</button></td>
        <td class="td1"><button id="alt3" class="altbutton">TAB3</button></td>
        <td class="td1"><button id="alt4" class="altbutton">TAB4</button></td>
        <td class="td1"><button id="alt5" class="altbutton">TAB5</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: can u show you html code

Comment: can u show your Css which used to this code as like that '#ust3tab', 'td1', 'altbutton'

Comment: @Ghokun It will be much easier if you put your code in **http://jsfiddle.net/** so other can have a look :)

Comment: Ok I did : http://jsfiddle.net/Ghokun/zgSDG/  :)

Comment: why you using **min-height** ??

Comment: Because button will be cropped to text size if I do not use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

to your td.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/F9aQw/

```
       .altbutton:hover {
           border:2px solid red;
           };​
```

Comment: Nope still not working try to open this  http://jsfiddle.net/Ghokun/zgSDG/embedded/result/ with FF and IE.

Comment: I can't say bout IE, but in FF it works, at least in my FF 11.0 for Ubuntu. but I'll look into it.

Comment: I've cheked in IE 9 the link you posted here, and it works ok

Comment: Thanks I guess the problem is with IE 8 and previous

Comment: Could not find a direct solution to my problem. I guess i will just cheat with adding border to all then change the color only.